# Foreign keys cannot be created using SQL ALchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

The code in the model is as follows

```
class User(db.Model):

id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
nickname = db.Column(db.String(64),index = True,unique = True)
email = db.Column(db.String(120),index = True,unique= True)
posts = db.relationship('Post',backref = 'author' , lazy = 'dynamic')

def __repr__(self):
    return '<User %r>' % (self.nickname)

class Post(db.Model):

id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
body = db.Column(db.String(140))
timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

def __repr__(self):
    return '<Post %r>' % (self.body)
```

Then synchronize models to the database using migrate.
But the ***post*** table in the database does not generate a foreign key pointing to the ***user*** table.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add what database and connector if/any you are using.

Comment: What is the `User` table name? Is it `users` or just `user`?

Answer (score 0):

```
post_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
relationship(
    "Post",
    foreign_keys=[post_id],
    primaryjoin="User.post_id == Post.id",
    backref=backref("author", lazy="dynamic")
)
```